# Use PHP in UIWebview on iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c

Is this possible??

If i wanted to put a UIWebview into my app, could i make mysql db calls and use other PHP functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell your UIWebView to load a URL of a file sitting on a web server. That URL can be to a PHP page that can do... well, anything a PHP page can do. Database stuff, etc.

But that's happening on the SERVER. PHP is a SERVER-based technology. PHP doesn't run on the BROWSER, which is what a UIWebView is.

Comment: ok, thats fine then. i was just wondering the limitation of plugging a PHP page into a UIWebview

Answer (score 2):

No. Think of the `UIWebView` as a web browser, as opposed to a web server. It is effectively a way of embedding Mobile Safari into your application.

Comment: ahh ok, so if i put a PHP page into the UIWebview that had database calls on it, then nothing would show up or am i not understanding?

Comment: Apparently you can install Apache on an iPhone but only by jailbreaking!

Comment: The view renders HTML and Javascript. Anything else is just going to appear as plain text, in exactly the same way as it would on any desktop web browser.

Comment: Oh, and I'm sure you **can** install Apache on a jailbroken iPhone, but that sounds like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut!