# Dyamic CSS not loading in iOS

Tags: ios, css, html

I am point the href of css link to a php script. Works good in all browser. When i try the same in iOs its not working.
If I put the manual entry instead of programtic entry it works.

The source that works

```
<html>
<head>
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/assets?action=writeCss&cssId=38">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The source that not works

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/assets?action=writeCss&cssId=<?php echo "38"; ?>">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you sure localhost is accessible from wherever you're testing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use PHP in a UIWebView? I think you can't run PHP on the iOS, PHP runs on the server and not on the browser.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8326238/1146089) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326347/1146089).